# aws multipart fileupload using java sdk

Tags: aws-sdk

I am working on Highlevel multipart fileupload on  aws sdk using java.But i need few clarification on below points .please help me!!

1 :  What happens if there was network failure during uploading file parts?How do we re-upload ? will  re-upload start from the beginning or will it get resume?

2 : Which provide better performance comparatively between low level and high level api

3 : any websites that provide  Production ready code.

Thanks in advance..............

Answer (score 0):

1. Resuming completly depends on how you have handled your implementation where you hold upload id and last part number that was uploaded. This is all you need to know to start resuming uploads in  s3. That is the whle benfit of AWS S3 multipart Uploads.
2. Obviously High level API are good for your application if you really look forward to get progress of every upload you make. But that again depends on your application. for java sdk AWS Documentaion is too good.
3. Please go through AWS Java SDK Examples :https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/usingHLmpuJava.html

If you are implementaing in Java AWS Docs will be sufficient